# Render error ,Missing constraint in Constraint layout,Failed to initiate more classes .All Error at time

Tags: android

All error occurs at same time I'm using latest version 3.0 but this error can't be solved I tried many ways

1. style ->theme
2. invalid cache
3. Change API but all does not work kindly need for your help.. 
   drag button in UI but button not show on UI and above error occur .

Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.yousa.myapplication3.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="69dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="102dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping button error solved but above mentioned error not going :(

Comment: use this line ? where??

Comment: In your build.gradle. Check the version of constraintlayout

Comment: could not find compile arguments => error occured to use to use above lines